# Techniques to prove that solutions of ODE are defined for all time.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis, reference-request, dynamical-systems, alternative-proof

**What are the main techniques for proving that the solutions of ODE are defined for all times?** Obviously I refer to qualitative study of $$y'=f(t,y)$$ with $f:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n $ at least $C^0$. The standard way is to use classical reults (e.g. prove that $f$ is sublinear or globally lipschitz) but these rusults are often not applicable. In this case I try to show that the solutions are bounded (it is known that *if the orbits are bounded then the solutions are defined for all time*). To do this I usually try one of the following techniques:

- I look for a constant of the motion and I study the level sets to understand the shape of the orbits (and see if they are bounded);
- I find a particular solution that is a closed and curve (e.g. a circle): in fact for the uniqueness the orbits can not intersect and therefore all orbits that start from inside this closed curve will have to remain there and will therefore be limited;
- I study the function $h(t): = x^2(t) + y^2(t)$: I make the derivative and I try to show that it is limited;
- I try a change of variables (e.g. polar coordinates) that simplifies the equations.

---

In conclusion:

1) **Do you know other general techniques to show that the orbits are bounded?**

2) However, boundedness is only a sufficient condition to prove that solutions are defined for all time! **In case the solutions are unbounded how can I prove that they are defined for all time?** For example consider $$\begin{cases}\dot x=-y^2\\
\dot y = x^2\end{cases}$$ or $$\begin{cases}\dot x=y^2\\
\dot y = x^2\end{cases}$$
The level sets of the constants of motion ($E:=x^3\pm y^3$) of these system are open and unbounded curve. In this case the only techniques that I know is to cumpute $t=\int^{+\infty}_{x_0}...dx$ and understand if this integral converges or diverges (for other details see the end of this page: [Qualitative study of $ \dot x = - y^2$, $\dot y= x^2 $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2837014/qualitative-study-of-dot-x-y2-dot-y-x2?rq=1)).

3) Advice on books and readings about this problem are welcome.

Comment: The simplest approach and really the standard, if there is one: Gronwall.

Comment: @JohnB it's included in the case "$f(t,y)$ sublinear in $y$".

Comment: The first and third approaches can be subsumed under [Lyapunov function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_function).

Comment: @user539887 good idea! Thanks.

Comment: If you have some compact domain and vector field points inside of it along its boundary, this also guarantees that solutions that start on boundary are defined for all $ t \geqslant 0$. Also, I remember a theorem which states that you can always transform a system of differential equations in such way that it has the same integral curves as an original one, but there is no finite time blow-up. Sadly, I can't find a reference with this theorem right now.

Comment: @Evgeny I tried to find a reference for the autonomous case on an open set (see [Any differential equation has a complete reparametrization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2816549/any-differential-equation-has-a-complete-reparametrization#comment5812032_2816549)), and the only thing I found is Mariano Suárez-Álvarez' more than five-year-old answer to [“Completing” a vector field on a non-compact manifold M](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378783/completing-a-vector-field-on-a-non-compact-manifold-m?rq=1): it uses quite advanced methods in differential geometry.

Comment: @user539887 I vaguely remember that this thing for $\mathbb{R}^n$ was called something like "Vinograd regularization", but googling this didn't help. If I'm not mistaking anything, the method was basically to go from $\dot{x} = F(x)$ to $\dot{u} = F(u)/\sqrt{1 + \| F(u) \|^2}$. But I still can't find where I've seen this trick or is it even working.

Comment: @user539887 By the way, I kind of found the reference: in [Nemytskii-Stepanov book](https://books.google.ru/books?id=3-mpZDFifoYC&pg=PA50&lpg=PA50&dq=nemytskii+stepanov+vinograd+theorem&source=bl&ots=a8eJDsuE0S&sig=lbSIQMo9qmxdCR66EiFgKPR3Hik&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj8_5TF6ojcAhVEkCwKHfmdBkoQ6AEIOzAD#v=onepage&q=nemytskii%20stepanov%20vinograd%20theorem&f=false) (p.19) there is Vinograd theorem which states that reparameterization that makes vector field complete exists. However, they do it differently than I remembered. At least some reference exists :)

Comment: @Evgeny A very good reference.

Comment: @Evgeny Could you give some information on that paper [55] by P. E. (rather R.E.?) Vinograd in Nemytskii-Stepanov book? I don't have access to the bibliography.

Comment: @user539887 Me neither at this moment. I even can't find some pdf to check what was that reference. Russian version doesn't have it as far as I can see.

Answer (score 3):

An answer to 1):

In mathematical population biology, a *totally competitive* system  of ODEs is defined as
$$
x'_i = x_i f_i(x_1, \dots, x_n), \quad i = 1, \dots, n,
$$
where
$$
\frac{\partial f_i}{\partial x_j} < 0 
$$
(of course $f_i$ are assumed to be $C^1$, at least).  The natural phase space is the *nonnegative orthant* $C = \{\, x = (x_1, \dots, x_n) : x_i \ge 0$ for all $i = 1, \dots, n \,\}$.

As $x_i$ represents the population density of the $i$-th species, only solutions that are bounded for positive time have biological significance.  There is a very simple, but extremely useful, sufficient condition for such boundedness:

> For each $i = 1, \dots, n\ $  there is $x_i^* > 0$ such that $f_i(0, \dots, 0, x_i^*, 0, \dots, 0) = 0$.

Indeed, let $x \in C$ be such that for some $j$, $x_j > x_j^*$.  Then
$$
f_j(x) = f_j(x_1, \dots, x_{j-1}, x_j, x_{j+1}, \dots, x_n) \le  f_j(0, \dots, 0, x_j, 0, \dots, 0) < f_j(0, \dots, 0, x_j^*, 0, \dots, 0) = 0.
$$
From this it follows that all solutions are attracted toward the ($n$-dimensional) parallelepiped $[0, x_1^*] \times \ldots \times [0, x_n^*]$. Consequently, each solution in $C$ is defined for all positive times $t$.

For (much) more on such systems, see, e.g., Zhao's book [Dynamical Systems in Population Biology](https://www.springer.com/la/book/9780387003085).  See also the classical paper by M. W. Hirsch [Systems of differential equations which are competitive or cooperative: III. Competing species](https://doi.org/10.1088/0951-7715/1/1/003).

Comment: I do not work in the field of mathematical population biology but your example is interesting. Thanks for your support.